# Kill process by name

Tags: command-line, process, kill, pkill

I am using bash to start several instances of one python program, like this:

```
python example.py -id $i
```

where `$i` is the id given to the instance. All the processes are started on the same user, and imagine I am unable of keeping track of the process IDs. Would it be possible to kill the specific instance just by the command (with id) that called it? For example something like `pkill 'python example.py -id 2'` which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Try `pkill -f python example.py -id 2`. The man page for pkill explains the `-f` flag (see `man pkill`). And generally, it's a good idea to quote your variables (`"$i"` instead of just `$i`).

Comment: If the processes are running under the current shell, then the `jobs` command and then `kill %2` or whatnot may be of use, to use the shell job control functionality.

Comment: `python example.py -id $i | id_$1=$!` will save pid of python command into id_$i variable. Later you can kill desired ID process by `kill -9 ${id_$1}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `pkill -fx`:

```
pkill -fx 'python example.py -id 2'
```

The `-f` option to `pkill` makes matching happen against the full command line, not just the process name, and `-x` forces the pattern to match the full command exactly, not just any substring of it (just like with `grep -x`).  You'll need `-x` to avoid matching command lines that possibly had further digits at the end, like `20` or `203`.

Answer (score -1):

`kill $(ps -ef | grep '[s]earch-string' | sed -re 's/[[:blank:]]+/\t/g' | cut -f2)`

1. `ps -ef` : gets process list with arguments
2. `grep` : filters for the record you want the `[]` is to stop grep finding its self.
3. `sed -re 's/[[:blank:]]+/\t/g'` : converts space to a single tab
4. `cut -f2` : extracts the pid field

Note:
`ps` is not very portable, there is one for posix, one for bsd, one for system-v. The Gnu one looks like it tries to be compatible with all.

Comment: @roaima's comment may be a simpler answer.

Comment: Not really portable: `ps: unknown option -- f
usage: ps [-AaceHhjkLlmrSTuvwx] [-M core] [-N system] [-O fmt] [-o fmt] [-p pid]
          [-t tty] [-U username] [-W swap]`

Comment: `ps` is not very portable, there is one for posix, one for bsd, one for system-v. The Gnu one looks like it tries to be compatible with all. If you want help with `ps` then you will have to tell us which OS and version of `ps`.